# Altium Designer - Cannot change Designator rotation

Tags: altium

In the PCB editor, I want to set a designator rotation to 45 degrees. However when I try and set its rotation to 45 degrees, it automatically resets it to 0 degrees.

I found that I can still change the rotation by 90 degree increments. I also have other designators that are at a 45 degree rotation. I suddenly cannot change the designator rotation, except in 90 degree increments.

Comment: Is the designator Locked?

Comment: The designator is not locked

Answer (score 2):

If you set autoposition to other than manual it seems to do that.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sephro, I found that if I set autoposition to manual it allows me to specify the rotation. Originally my autoposition was set to Left-Above which didn't allow me to specify the rotation. I wouldn't have thought of changing the autoposition, so thank you for that! :)